# Stripe Payment method sofort (or instant payment)

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

on my page already integrated paypal and stripe card .. i wanna integrate stripe instant payment (sofort)  ... i need to add few code lines to develop it but a im just a big amateur!

After line 100 i would to add acourding to the written code from the previos developer if(getPaymentMethod === "8"){code for the stripe instant payment}

The **getPaymentMethod === "4" is stripe card**! **I would really appriciate your help!Thansk**

```html
<script>
    /**
     * @settings
     */
    var backgroundColor = '#f0f0f0';
    jQuery('body').css('background', backgroundColor);
    jQuery(document).ready(() => {
        jQuery(".buttonView,.searchView,.TableLayout,.copyrightLayout").remove();
        jQuery(".headerLayout .View").css({ "width" : "800px" });
        jQuery(".MainLayout .ViewMainLayout").css({ "width" : "800px" });
        jQuery(".headerFirstLayout .View").css({ "width" : "800px" });
    });

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="view/checkout_layout.css#">

<div class="CheckoutLayout">

    <div class="CheckoutLayoutLeft">
        <div class="CheckoutList">
            <div class="CheckoutListTitle">{$eu_update_045}</div>
            {include="page/checkout/listview"}
        </div>
        <div class="CheckoutList Top">
            {include="page/checkout/terms"}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="CheckoutLayoutRight">
        {include="page/checkout/payment"}
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        currency: '{$paypal_code}',
        locale  : '{$lang_code}',
        key     : '{$stripe_publish_key}',
        token: function(token) { $("#stripeToken").val(token.id); $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email); $("#amountInCents").val(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100)); $("#stripePaymentSubmit").submit(); }
    });
</script>
<form id="stripePaymentSubmit" action="app/payments/stripe/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="{$price_decimal}" id="amountInDollars" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeAmount" name="stripeAmount" value="{$price_decimal}" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeName" name="stripeName" value="{$paypal_text}" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeCurrency" name="stripeCurrency" value="{$paypal_code}" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeProductId" value="{$checkout_id}" name="stripeProductId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="amountInCents" name="amountInCents" />
</form>

<script>
    function Checkout(){
        var payment_method = jQuery("input[name=selectPayment]").is(":checked");
        var payment_buy_terms = jQuery("#buy_terms").is(":checked");
        var payment_buy_terms_cancel = jQuery("#buy_cancel").is(":checked");

        if(payment_method === false){ alert("{$eu_update_052}"); }
        else if(payment_buy_terms === false){ alert("{$eu_update_053}"); }
        else if(payment_buy_terms_cancel === false){ alert("{$eu_update_054}"); }
        else {

            if (payment_method) {
                var getPaymentMethod = jQuery("input[name=selectPayment]:checked").val();

                if (getPaymentMethod === "1") {
                    jQuery("#onSubmitPayPal").submit();
                }
                if (getPaymentMethod === "2"){
                    box('banktransfer', '{$payment_string},{$price_decimal}');
                    jQuery(".CheckoutLayout").html('<div class="CheckoutFinishedLayout"><b>{$eu_update_040}</b><br><br>{$eu_update_044}.</div>');
                }
                if (getPaymentMethod === "3"){
                    box('bitcoin', '{$price_decimal}&pay={$bitcoin_string}&btc={$bitcoin_address}');
                }
                if(getPaymentMethod === "7"){
                    var PaymentObject = {
                        page:       'klarnaCheckout',
                        amount:     '{$price_decimal}',
                        title:      '{$paypal_text}',
                        currency:   '{$pay_currency_line}',
                        is_category:'{$get.category}',
                        is_push:    '{$get.push}',
                        is_gallery: '{$get.galerie}',
                        productId:  '{$get.id}',
                        checkoutId: '{$checkout_id}'
                    };
                    jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "base.php", data: PaymentObject }).done(response => { location.href = response; });
                }
                if(getPaymentMethod === "4"){

                    var Amout = '{$price_decimal}';
                    var amountInCents = Math.floor(Amout * 100);
                    var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor(Amout * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

                    handler.open({name: '{$copyrightname}', description: '{$paypal_text} (' + displayAmount + ' {$pay_currency})', amount: amountInCents,});
                    $(window).on('popstate', function() { handler.close(); });

                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="paypal.js?callback=1"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(() => {
    payPalCheckout.setOptions({
        'business'      : '{$paypal_id}',
        'amount'        : '{$price_decimal}',
        'item_name'     : '{$paypal_text}',
        'item_number'   : '{$checkout_id}',
        'currency_code' : '{$paypal_code}',
        'cancel_url'    : '{$base_url}mylist?id={$product_id}&sk=cancel',
        'return_url'    : '{$base_url}mylist?id={$product_id}&sk=checkout',
        'notify_url'    : '{$base_url}app/payments/paypal/index.php'
    });
    payPalCheckout.onExecute();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [Legacy Checkout](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout) to accept payments with Stripe. This is an old integration that only allows users to pay by card.

If you want to accept more payment methods (like Sofort), you should use some newer integration, like [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout) or [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements).

Comment: Ok that means it is not possible to use sofort with old integrtion just with the new!

Comment: Yes that's correct.